# Question on Uniform Conergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence

I need to show that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty$$(\frac {x}{2})^k$ does not converge uniformly on (-2, 2)

I know I have to show that $\sup_{x\in X}\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert\nrightarrow0 $ as $n\rightarrow\infty$,  because if the sequence of partial sums does not converge uniformly then the series can't either.

but I need some help setting up $\sup_{x\in X}\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\lvert $

Comment: You could note the terms of the series do not converge uniformly to zero on $(-2,2)$.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that the given sequence is a partial sum of a geometric sequence hence

$$\mu_n(x):=f(x)-f_n(x)=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty(x/2)^k=(x/2)^{n+1}\frac{1}{1-x/2}$$
 so we have that
 $$\sup_{x\in(-2,2)}|f(x)-f_n(x)|\ge\lim_{x\to2}\mu_n(x)=+\infty$$ and thus the sequence cannot converge uniformly.

Comment: this is sort of what i was looking for..good answer

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (x/2)^k.$$

Now pick $x=2-2/n$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose it did converge uniformly to a function $f$. Then there would exist an index $n$ with the property that $$\left| \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \frac x 2 \right)^k - f(x) \right|  < 1$$ for all $x \in (-2,2)$. On the other hand, the finite sum is bounded on this interval but the limit function $f$ (which you can compute explicitly as a geometric series) is not bounded. Thus the difference cannot, for any $n$, be uniformly less than $1$.